# SQLite cannot read field in table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite file

```
CREATE TABLE `mall` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `kordinat`  TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

this is select code

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM mall", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

when I run those code, It work, but when I change "name" field to  "kordinat" field, it error and says "no such column: kordinat".
please help

Comment: **1** - Remove these useless **`** characters. **2** - uninstall and reinstall you app.

Comment: those sql is not from my android code, it from sqlite file

Comment: My comment above is still valid.

Comment: uninstall and install it again, you probabelly changed the database schema without upgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no such column: kordinat

This is because at first time `mall` table is created with **column** `name` and when you are changing it to `kordinat`, you are trying to create the table with **same name but different schema**, so this is not creating the table because table with that name already exists with previous schema.

**Uninstall** the application and **Re-Install** the application to you Debugging device.